# How can I insert a sum directly into table?

Tags: mysql, count

```
INSERT INTO score_1a (red, blue, purple, green, yellow, cyan)  
VALUES (sum(red), sum(blue), sum(purple), sum(green), sum(yellow), sum(cyan) )
```

This gives the following error:

> Invalid use of group function.

How can I fix this?

Comment: ......a sum of what?

Comment: a sum of the values in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will help

```
INSERT INTO score_1a (red, blue, purple, green, yellow, cyan)  
select  sum(red), sum(blue), sum(purple), sum(green), sum(yellow), sum(cyan)  
from Score_1a  -- Use other table name if u need from other table
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Unfortunately this provides the following error: Operand should contain 1 column(s).

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a source for `SUM`s, one way to do it is using a `SELECT` statement

```
INSERT INTO score_1a (red, blue, purple, green, yellow, cyan)  
SELECT
    SUM(red), SUM(blue), SUM(purple), SUM(green), SUM(yellow), SUM(cyan)
FROM
    tbl2
```

Comment: Awesome! This does work! Didn;t know you needed to use a subquery

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `score_1a` (`red`,`blue`, `purple`, `green`,`yellow`, `cyan`)  ( SELECT SUM(red), SUM(blue), SUM(purple), SUM(green), SUM(yellow), SUM(cyan) FROM score_1a );
```